# Make a bootable image of installed linux

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, disk-image

Is there a way to create a bootable disk of the installed linux OS retaining all the settings and programs. i.e i'd wanted to restore all the settings and installed programs of my OS when i install it on pc without having to go through the process of re-installing every thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily remaster Ubutnu. you can use many applications to do that(remastersys-ubuntu builder-UCK - ....). But personally i advise you to use relinux.

[Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux) is a great step by step tutorial how to use and obtain an iso of your current running system using relinux